# Randomization macro

Tags: r, random, macros, phylogeny

I try to measure the phylogenetic signal in two variables, a discrete and a continuous one. To do so, I use the δ-statistic (Borges et al 2018) and the K-statistic (Blomberg 2003), respectively. I have a tree, and two vectors corresponding to my variables. The line of code for these two statistics are the following:

1) `delta(vector, tree, lambda0, se, sim, thin, burn)`

2) `phylosig(tree, vector, method = "K")`

I get a single value each time. But I would like to randomize my vectors to test the significance of the orignal values. I would like to do 1000 repetitions and then proceed to a simple test of significance but, as I am a new R user, I have no idea how to do it. I think of something like this:

For δ:

```
%first repetition
random_vector <- sample(vector)
random_delta <- delta(vector, tree, lambda0, se, sim, thin, burn)
write.xlsx(random_delta, path)

%second repetition
random_vector <- sample(random_vector)
random_delta <- delta(vector, tree, lambda0, se, sim, thin, burn)
write.xlsx(random_delta, path, append = TRUE)
```

And on, and on, until 1000 δ-statistics stored in a single .xlsx, ready to be used in a test.

For K, I guess it is a bit different since it is not a vector anymore but a table with two columns (species, values):

```
%first repetition
random_vector <- sample(vector)
names(random_vector) <- tree$tip.label
random_K <- phylosig(tree, vector, method = "K")
write.xlsx(random_K, path)

%second rep
random_vector <- sample(random_vector)
names(random_vector) <- tree$tip.label
random_K <- phylosig(tree, vector, method = "K")
write.xlsx(random_delta, path, append = TRUE)
```

Etc.

I thought of that, but maybe someone has another idea. Either way, I am in.

I hope I have made myself clear.

EDIT:
Thank you for your answers. Yes, a loop is totally what I need. And yes, write all the values in one vector seems more approriate, I agree with you.

With the δ-statistic, the phylogenetic signal is all the more important in the data as δ is high. But what is high? That is why I want to do 1000 iterations, to calcultate the p-value and demonstrate if the original value is 'exceptional' or not. Same with K, which is comprised between 0 and 1 in the presence of a phylogenetic signal.

Here is a more explicite example:

```
> library(phytools)
> trait_delta <- c(2,1,3,1,1,3,1,3,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,3,1,1)
> trait_K <- c(2,1,3,1,1,3,1,3,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,3,1,1)
> set.seed(25)
> ns <- 20
> tree <- rtree(ns)
> plot(tree)
> 
> #delta
> lambda0 <- 0.1
> se <- 0.5
> sim <- 10000
> thin <- 10
> burn <- 100
> 
> delta <- delta(trait_delta,tree,lambda0,se,sim,thin,burn)
> rand_values_delta <- c(print(delta))
>
> #to loop 999 times
> rand_trait_delta <- sample(trait_delta)
> rand_delta <- delta(rand_trait_delta,tree,lambda0,se,sim,thin,burn)
> rand_values_delta <- append(rand_values_delta, print(rand_delta), after =
> length(rand_values_delta+1))
> 
>
> #K
> names(trait_K) <- tree$tip.label
> K <- phylosig(tree, trait_K, method = "K")
> rand_values_K <- c(K)
>
> #to loop 999 times
> rand_trait_K <- sample(trait_K)
> names(rand_trait_K) <- tree$tip.label
> rand_K <- phylosig(tree, rand_trait_K, method = "K")
> rand_values_K <- append(rand_values_K, rand_K, after =
> length(rand_values_K+1))
```

Comment: im struggling to understand what you are doing and what you want. I feel like you are after a for loop where you iterate over a series of values. why are you writing them all to a file? why not put them all into a vector or dataframe and then write the whole thing to one file? That will save on clutt in your folder

Comment: `phytools::phylosig` has an option to set the number of randomizations (default 1000). I don't think you need to randomize the tip data beyond that, as the test already uses the randomization to generate a null distribution.

Comment: As for the `delta` test. This is appears to be a Bayesian method. So it should provide a measure of uncertainty by default (posterior distribution), without the need of randomizations and re-fitting.

Comment: If you still need to randomize and repeat, please provide a minimal reproducible example of your attempts so we have something more specific to work with.

Comment: @RAB yes, a loop is exactly what I need, and yes, putting all the values in a single vector sounds good to me.

Comment: @teofil I edited my question and provided a more explicite example of what I have in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still a bit hazy on exactly what you are doing, but hopefully this points you in the right direction:

```
n <- 10000            # run this many iterations 
results <- rep(NA, n) # create an empty vector to store all the values

for (i in 1:n){

  # get the random vector for this iteration
  random_vector <- sample(vector) 

  # save the value you output
  results[i] <- delta(vector, tree, lambda0, se, sim, thin, burn) 

}

# write the single vector to file
write.xlsx(results, path)
```

This is untested as I don't know what `vector` or `path` are, I just used them from your code